# Previous/next buttons in iOS are disabled for input that is hidden/revealed via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Take a look at [this](http://oliverjash.github.com/FormAccordion/) in Mobile Safari on iOS. When a value is found inside the first input, the second input is shown - but the button to toggle to the next input in the form (fixed to the keyboard in iOS) is disabled.

Is there any way I can trigger something so that this input is found and I can click next?

Comment: I know this is quite old but did you come up with a resolution for your problem? Facing the same issue with quite a complex UI and I'd be interested to know if its possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm shooting from the hip here, but you could try one of these:

- Setting hidden fields to `visibility:hidden; height:0` instead of `display:none`.

  - Probable downside: If this works, the `next` button will be always active.
- On line 136 of `form-accordion.js`, do something along the lines of `$this.blur(); $('body').focus(); $this.focus();`. Although fugly, it probably is going to work.

Comment: Hmm, I can't afford to do the first option because the nature of the plugin means there might be fields following that are not hidden - this of course means you have to toggle through the invisible ones to get to the one you need to be at. As for the second option, interesting idea. However, the blur closes the iOS keyboard and then focus doesn't seem to bring it back. Strange…

Comment: Ah. Blurring and focusing the input isn't going to work in the context of this plugin - because it has to loop through each input to test if it is empty, so it's going to try to blur and focus all of the inputs, the selected one being the last. Hence why it is closing the keyboard in iOS.

Comment: Funny enough, if you press "done" and re-focus manually, all works as expected. Thus, I would suggest remembering which input changed originally, blurring and re-focusing after the iteration.

Comment: Yeah… It's going to take some thinking, though. Remembering which input was changed originally is not an easy task because the way that the event is triggered on multiple fields at once.